# Pass Data to MVC Action Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to pass data to the action method below from another action method or another view. Then it will be used where the arrow points. But this action method already has a parameter and get value from its own view. And it mustn't have more than one parameter. I don't know how.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `TempData` like below examples:

**pass data from action to another action**

```
public ActionResult Action_A()
{
    TempData["Data"] = "ABC";

    return View();
}


public ActionResult Action_B()
{
    var data = TempData["Data"];

    return View();
}
```

**pass data from action view to another action**

Action View

```
 @{
    TempData["Data"] = "hello";
  }
  <p>This is a Demo</p>
```

Another Action

```
  public ActionResult Action_B()
    {
        var data = TempData["Data"];

        return View();
    }
```